# How to build a Typescript object using a functional compose style

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'd like to use a functional composed pipeline to build up an object, while keeping type safety. What types should I use for the compose-able functions to stitch them together?

I have an object with some input data, and my aim is to use compose-able functions to perform calculations on the input data.

For example, in the code below, I start off with a sideLength value; then add the calculated values (area, circumference and cubeArea) with three separate functions; each responsible for its own knowledge. Some calculations like cubeArea are based on previous calculations in the pipeline.

```js
import * as R from "ramda";

interface ISquare {
  sideLength: number;
  area: number;
  circumference: number;
  cubeArea: number;
}
type ISquareBase = Pick<ISquare, "sideLength">;
type ISquareWithArea = Pick<ISquare, "area" | "sideLength">;
type ISquareWithCircumference = Pick<ISquare, "circumference" | "sideLength">;
type ISquareWithCubeArea = Pick<ISquare, "cubeArea" | "sideLength">;

const addArea = (shape: ISquareBase): ISquareWithArea => ({
  ...shape,
  area: shape.sideLength * shape.sideLength
});

const addCircumference = (shape: ISquareBase): ISquareWithCircumference => ({
  ...shape,
  circumference: shape.sideLength * 4
});

const addCubeArea = (shape: ISquareWithArea): ISquareWithCubeArea => ({
  ...shape,
  cubeArea: shape.area * shape.sideLength
});

const buildSquare = R.compose(
  addArea, // { sideLength: 2, area: 4 }
  addCircumference, // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference: 8 }
  addCubeArea // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference: 8, cubeArea: 8 }
);

const initialSquare: ISquareBase = { sideLength: 2 };

// The below line gives typescript error:
// Argument of type 'Pick<ISquare, "sideLength">' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<ISquare, "sideLength" | "area">'.
// Property 'area' is missing in type 'Pick<ISquare, "sideLength">' but required in type 'Pick<ISquare, "sideLength" | "area">'.
const calculatedSquare: ISquare = buildSquare(initialSquare);

console.log(calculatedSquare);
// Expect: { sideLength: 2, circumference: 8, area: 4, cubeArea: 8 }
```

Typescript is giving a type error when I try to use buildSquare, the composed function above.

```
Argument of type 'Pick<ISquare, "sideLength">' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<ISquare, "sideLength" | "area">'.
Property 'area' is missing in type 'Pick<ISquare, "sideLength">' but required in type 'Pick<ISquare, "sideLength" | "area">'.
```

I can relax the type signatures to get it working, but then I lose the ability to ensure with types that addCubeArea can't run before the area calculation in addArea is run.

How can I do this while keeping type safety? Is there an alternate type structure I can use?

Comment: Btw, I would use a curried constructor instead of composition. Even if the order in which properties are passed varies, you could create custom-made wrappers (e.g. `f => c => a => d => b => f(a) (b) (c) (d)` to modify the constructor accordingly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is that the functions you are composing need to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), otherwise there's no way for the compiler to keep track of the fact that, for example, if `sq` has an `area` property already, `addCircumference(sq)` will produce an object with both an `area` and  a `circumference`.  Your current typing only guarantees that `addCircumference()`'s output has a `circumference`, but fails to specify whether there's an `area` or not.  For all the type system knows, maybe you don't copy `area` into the output.

First, since I don't have ramda typings in my environment, I assume that `compose()` as you are using it acts something like this:

```
declare namespace R {
  export function compose<I0, I1, I2, O>(
    f: (x: I0) => I1,
    g: (x: I1) => I2,
    h: (x: I2) => O
  ): (x: I0) => O;
}
```

Now let's redo the signatures for your three functions:

```
const addArea = <T extends { sideLength: number }>(
  shape: T
): T & { area: number } => ({
  ...shape,
  area: shape.sideLength * shape.sideLength
});

const addCircumference = <T extends { sideLength: number }>(
  shape: T
): T & { circumference: number } => ({
  ...shape,
  circumference: shape.sideLength * 4
});

const addCubeArea = <T extends { sideLength: number; area: number }>(
  shape: T
): T & { cubeArea: number } => ({
  ...shape,
  cubeArea: shape.area * shape.sideLength
});
```

All of those types essentially take an input of (an appropriately [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)) generic type `T`, and produce an output of type `T` [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) with an object type representing the added properties.

This part still works:

```
const buildSquare = R.compose(
  addArea, // { sideLength: 2, area: 4 }
  addCircumference, // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference: 8 }
  addCubeArea // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference: 8, cubeArea: 8 }
);
```

But now the type of `buildSquare` is

```
const buildSquare: <T extends { sideLength: number; }>(x: T) => 
  T & { area: number; } & { circumference: number; } & { cubeArea: number; }
```

meaning that `buildSquare` takes an object of type `T` constrained to `{sideLength: number}`, and returns an object of type `T` with the three numeric properties `area`, `circumference`, and `number` added to it.  Looks reasonable to me.

Let's test it:

```
const initialSquare = { sideLength: 2 };    
const calculatedSquare: ISquare = buildSquare(initialSquare); // okay
```

No error now, hooray! Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCBK8A3gFDzwgAemA9jAC7wBmAromHQJbWLxjUo10IADwBJAAwAaeKICM00QCZpAeQB8AClJkmALngaK+iQEp4AXjUz52sgHN9h47LOWZy2-AAWjo+9dWKtomvsbiAfAqANzEAL7ExByIdCAwjDgIogDKAI7MsAgkZOgcoAAyIIh2dD5IzCgARqkxZAVQ+oj1TTAtvBwwYPWMqZW4HV3N2oNNAIJw7XWNk-HEfIjoDFDAwHMgUBbwwgAq5BQpiMDoRPAl5ZXVtZ1LMPCxmtroXlCYIPpHxCF4CcAGTXNrjZ6vCxWDRFeAAOkRn2+IEk2nBNy+P3htxAFSqNXgACpMSicaU8fcanETDFVtwNvAtsAAML9QYoYZwNgIcyHE6Uc6Xa64-EPCHdV7vYpY35AgF-eCgwh9AZDEY8iWpKFuWHaRE42Voshgdnq7ljUnY0VUrzE+AAFhpdLWjOZLOYs3mB2OpyFVxVNoJjwmPSZ8y1LzeWhlKL+CqBSuu0xAuwWT0lsWhBjhBuRP2NvE9qYjVpA8La9vz5aDD2dCVdDAazA4EGAuXycAOeHhfAE1CEMaZ2zT0gA9GORRSxTV9Mpw3t9A7Xujtmy1ZyNbhx5PA9PbXPpBiHdJTRuuaM5QAOFetNfFtPwCdTu7Bw8LhYn1Uci+a+BX08H1LG94lpBsGQYJIOE4KAIA7AoDj3V9xXgRRXhdCDeFgwZoBSds8gKYx4K7Plm1bfDOxADQoJguCCLgMD6XWagIHLCBqDsDQwGw5hcJACiCjAoA)

---

EDIT:  It's possible you've got Ramda's `compose()` function backwards (as I said, I'm not sure about the typings)... if so, then you will have a harder time with type inference.  That is, if `R.compose` looks like

```
declare namespace R {
  export function compose<I0, I1, I2, O>(
    h: (x: I2) => O,
    g: (x: I1) => I2,
    f: (x: I0) => I1
  ): (x: I0) => O;
}
```

Then you will get an error even if you switch the order of your arguments to it:

```
const buildSquare = R.compose(
  addCubeArea, // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference: 8, cubeArea: 8 }
  addCircumference, // error! { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference: 8 }
  addArea // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference }
); // error!
```

This is a known [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31738) with the [algorithm that supports higher-order generic function inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) introduced in [TypeScript 3.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions).  The algorithm does fairly well when types flow from left to right in function parameters, and fairly poorly when types are supposed to flow from right to left.  In this case, you will need to give up on type inference and do some manual specification of types somewhere.  For example, given the `R.compose()` definition here, you could manually specify the `I0`, `I1`, `I2`, and `O` types:

```
const buildSquare = R.compose<
  { sideLength: number },
  { sideLength: number; area: number },
  { sideLength: number; area: number; circumference: number },
  { sideLength: number; area: number; circumference: number; cubeArea: number }
>(
  addCubeArea, // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference: 8, cubeArea: 8 }
  addCircumference, // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference: 8 }
  addArea // { sideLength: 2, area: 4, circumference }
); // okay
```

(You could use your type aliases in that specification if you want to save keystrokes).  Or you could specify the concrete types for each argument to `R.compose()`:

```
const addAreaConcrete = (x: { sideLength: number }) => addArea(x);
const addCircumferenceConcrete = (x: { sideLength: number; area: number }) =>
  addCircumference(x);
const addCubeAreaConcrete = (x: {
  sideLength: number;
  area: number;
  circumference: number;
}) => addCubeArea(x);
const buildSquareConcrete = R.compose(
  addCubeAreaConcrete,
  addCircumferenceConcrete,
  addAreaConcrete
);
/*
const buildSquareConcrete: (x: {
    sideLength: number;
}) => {
    sideLength: number;
    area: number;
    circumference: number;
} & {
    cubeArea: number;
}
*/
```

That also works.  Personally in the case of an `R.compose()` where types should flow from right to left, I'd give up on using it entirely, unless you have some important reason why the following would be unacceptable for you:

```
const buildSquareManual = <T extends { sideLength: number }>(x: T) =>
  addCubeArea(addCircumference(addArea(x))); // okay
```

Okay, that's it for me.  Good luck again.

[Link to code with reversed compose](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCBK8A3gFDzwgAemA9jAC7wBmAromHQJbWLxjUo10IADwBJAAwAaeKICM00QCZpAeQB8AClJl4ACwBc8DRUNKAlPAC8a+CsnayAc0PHTsi9ZnKHTFyZniHjZy2mZ+poFWNioA3MQAvsTEHIh0IDCMOAiiAMoAjsywCCRk6BygADIgiI50BkjMKABG6XFkRVCGiI0tMG28HDBgjYzp1bhdPa3awy0AgnCdDc3TicR8iOgMUMDACyBQVvDCACrkFGmIwOhE8GWV1bX13Ssw8PGa2ui6UJgghidiGF4GcAGS3DqTV7vKJGErwAB0SO+vxA9nai0MKL+CPuICqNTq8AAVHcfji8QSngkzHF1twtvAdsAAMKDYYoUZwNgISzHM6US7XW6Ux51KG9d6fUrk-4goEA+DgwgDIYjMY8iXpGGeDTwpG42Xo1UcrnjOXYkC48r4sW6EnwAAsNLpG0ZzJZzHmiyOp3OQpuKtFhOeUz6TMxy0lHy0MtRAIVIKVt1mIH2Sxe0dheu0BstxtT6axsoRHQdlutDxDLqSboYTWYHAgwHyhTgRzwCL4AmoQmE2iDNqp4qj2vixsHVaeWvDkNHb3HA7uQ7tM5iEYOa5N6u5E3n7wny6nI8zrQ3GbD67A7J35q3hcjp4XxGlTN2nu9B2kAHpvyKVyGhjKOehiOtI15qpyGp7gAHOBXpppGMHvNoHo3lBu5ovAv7-se9TAXOYHbhhd7wMhiTtLs6bYX+k62oB8AEZGREQaa0EIIktK1gy2xUYsLLcGAcBpEcri4fR077vEQRvnsizGFxdayWykFmjyAlsMJvJGP4dHDqGrzrnOT7vEEqHvuham4ApcRKR6CHphpQkgCJfJifCwaSU+-TGZeMyWexa40rC9mflANn0ps9aNs2rZFE5Wkdl2-CCCAsbKQ5-GCVpxpoap7EJS5aLmXJByFWkQJxN+xKRYyDZNi2BTxdlRXhEQPieSefnSbC8KlABXl+ToIHzv0ZCsbemqjQkyZ9bwmWbtNiTEt+3FRfAKQcJwUAQHF7Z8npq6Me8ro8bwO3DNAaSNW2cq5E1+3wPVsUPWlm3bbtr2KWdYAXcwV0gDdzWaa1Mh7dpz1A3A5VvYgW0cDt4NcUAA)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. And yes, I had R.compose around the wrong way. Switching to R.pipe with your generic type annotations fixed it.